Multi-verse lyrics vertical misalignment using musixlyr for EB-Garamond font
I'm trying to write psalmody transcriptions to modern music notation using MusixTeX, but I'm observing some syllable vertical misalignment in a multi-verse lyrics created with musixlyr, when using EB-Garamond fonts. Here's my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{gregoriotex}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixdbr}

% http://icking-music-archive.org/software/musixtex/musixebgr.tex
\input{musixebgr}

\input{musixlyr}


\title{Psalm 24}

\author{Laércio de Sousa}


\def\neumnotes{\vnotes1.28\elemskip}


\NewDocumentCommand{\MediatioMark}{}{\loffset{0.5}{\lyric*{\GreStar}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\FlexaMark}{}{\loffset{0.5}{\lyric*{\GreDagger}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Accentus}{}{%
  %\zchar{5}{\fontfamily{greciliae}\selectfont }
  \roffset{0.1}{\zchar{5}{\LARGE \'{}}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{music}
  \parindent0pt
  \instrumentnumber{2}
  \setstaffs{1}{2}
  \setinterinstrument{1}{50pt}
  \setinterstaff{1}{14}
  \setclef{1}{\bass}
  \nobarnumbers
  \indivbarrules
  \sepbarrule{2}
  \resetlyrics

  \setlyrics{verse1}{%
    Ne-que_____ exsúltent\ super\ me\ ini-mi-ci me_-i.
    étenim\ univérsi\ qui\ sústinent\ te\ non\ confun-dén_-tur.%
  }

  \setlyrics{verse2}{%
    Vi-as_____ tuas,\ Dómine,\ de-món-stra mi_-hi,
    et\ sémitas\ tuas\ e-dó-ce me%
  }

  \setlyrics{verse3}{%
    Dí-ri_-ge\ me\ in\ veritáte\ tua,\ et do-ce me,
    quia\ tu\ es\ Deus\ sa-lú-tis me_-æ,
    et\ te\ sustínui\ tota di_-e.%
  }

  \setlyrics{verse4}{%
    Se-cún_____-dum\ misericórdiam\ tuam\ me-mén-to me-i tu,
    propter\ bonitátem\ tuam, Dó-mi-ne. %
  }

  \setlyrics{verse5}{%
    Dul-cis_____ et rec-tus Dó-mi-nus,
    propter\ hoc\ peccatóres\ viam\ do-cé_-bit.%
  }

  \setlyrics{verse6}{%
    Dí-ri_____-get\ mansuétos in iu-dí-ci-o,
    docébit\ mites\ vias su_-as.%
  }

  \assignlyrics{2}{verse1,verse2,verse3,verse4,verse5,verse6}

  \startpiece
  \znotes|&\loffset{1.5}{\verses{\lyric*{\textbf{1.}},\lyric*{\textbf{2.}},\lyric*{\textbf{3.}},\lyric*{\textbf{4.}},\lyric*{\textbf{5.}},\lyric*{\textbf{6.}}}}\en%
  \hardspace{4mm}%
  % Inchoatio
  \NOtes%
  \znh{H}\nh{L}|%
  \nh{c}&%
  \lyrlayout{\itshape}\nq{h}%
  \en%
  \neumnotes|&\isluru{0}{g}\nq{g}\tslur{0}{h}\nq{h}\hsk\en%
  % Tenor - Flexa
  \allbarrules\showdotbarrule\condotmultibarrule{1}%
  \bar%
  \notes%
  \zwqq{H}\wqq{L}|%
  \wqq{c}&%
  \lyrlayout{\leftlyrtrue}\wqq{h}%
  \sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk%
  \en%
  \NOtes%
  \znh{H}\nh{K}|%
  \nh{b}&%
  \lyrlayout{\bfseries}\Accentus\nq{h}\lyrlayout{}\nq{gg}%
  \en%
  \znotes|&\verses{,,\FlexaMark}\en%
  \bar%
  \allbarrules\showbarrule\conmultibarrule{1}%
  % Tenor - Mediatio
  \notes%
  \zwqq{H}\wqq{L}|%
  \wqq{c}&%
  \lyrlayout{\leftlyrtrue}\wqq{h}%
  \sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk%
  \en%
  \NOtes|&\lyrlayout{\itshape}\nq{gh}\lyrlayout{\bfseries}\Accentus\nq{i}\lyrlayout{}\lpar{h}\rpar{h}\nq{h}\nq{h}\en%
  \znotes|&\MediatioMark\en%
  \bar%
  % Tenor - Terminatio
  \notes%
  \zwqq{K}\wqq{M}|%
  \wqq{d}&%
  \lyrlayout{\leftlyrtrue}\wqq{h}%
  \sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk%
  \en%
  \NOtes%
  \roff{\znh{L}}\nh{L}|%
  \nh{b}&%
  \dotted\isluru{0}{h}\Accentus\lyrlayout{\bfseries}\nq{h}%
  \tslur{0}{g}\lyrlayout{}\lpar{g}\rpar{g}\nq{g}\nq{g}%
  \en%
  \setdoublebar%
  \endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}

Here's an excerpt of rendered output, where it's possible to see the lyrics misalignments (e.g. "meménto" in 4th line):

The same excerpt, rendered with default Computer Modern fonts, has no such misalignments:

What could be causing this problem? How could I fix it?
[SIDE QUESTION] Is there a better way to write the tenor part of the salmody, without all those \ s and \sks?


In the past I read a warning that there would be vertical misalignment when using a different type of letter, but I don't read it in the recent Musixdoc.pdf. However, using one of the letter types mentioned in the manual, there seems to be no vertical misalignment, as you discovered yourself. 2.  I can't compile your code: I get the warning "./musixebgr.tex:3: Text line con./musixebgr.tex:3: Text line contains an invalid character." Maybe this is the \ you want to get rid of. \ is a "special character defined by default" (6.3.4. of GregorioRef.pdf), "avoiding TeX interpretation".



For the reciting note we put the text in {This is one word, left aligned, if desired} and write, only for this word \NOTES (or less capitals), you can also add additional space by \addspace{dimension} outside \notes \en or by \hspace{dimension} inside \notes \en. By enlarging the space for the note, you do not need to \sk.

